# How to check the type of a type union in a function in typescript

Tags: typescript

Say I have this code:

```
interface A {
 type: 'a',
 value : number
}

interface B {
  type: 'b',
  value: string
}

type AB = A | B;

const db: Record<string, AB> = {
  param1: { type: 'a', value: 1234 }
};
```

I have code like this (over-simplified) that works well

```
function processParameter(parameter: string, expectedType: 'a' | 'b') {
  if (expectedType === 'a') {
    const result = db[parameter];
    if(!result) { throw new Error('Not found'); }
    if(result.type !== 'a') { throw new Error('Unexpected type'); }
    processA(result);
  }
  if (expectedType === 'b') {
    const result = db[parameter];
    if(!result) { throw new Error('Not found'); }
    if(result.type !== 'b') { throw new Error('Unexpected type'); }
    processB(result);
  }
}

function processA(value: A) {
  // ...
}

function processB(value: B) {
  // ...
}
```

I would like to refactor the code like this:

```
function processParameter(parameter: string, expectedType: 'a' | 'b') {
  if (expectedType === 'a') {
    const result = getAndCheck(parameter, expectedType);
    processA(result);
  }
  if (expectedType === 'b') {
    const result = getAndCheck(parameter, expectedType);
    processB(result);
  }
}

// I don't want to write all those lines here, is there a way ?
function getAndCheck(parameter: string, expectedType: 'a'): A;
function getAndCheck(parameter: string, expectedType: 'b'): B;
function getAndCheck(parameter: string, expectedType: 'a' | 'b'): AB {
  const result = db[parameter];
  if(!result) { throw new Error('Not found'); }
  if(result.type !== expectedType) { throw new Error('Unexpected type'); }
  return result;
}
```

Is there a way to simplify that ? Using generic ? using inference ? am I going the wrong way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic function to establish a relation between the `expectedType` parameter and the return type:

```
function getAndCheck<K extends AB['type']>(parameter: string, expectedType: K): Extract<AB, { type: K }> {
    const result = db[parameter] as AB;
    if (!result) { throw new Error('Not found'); }
    if (result.type !== expectedType) { throw new Error('Unexpected type'); }
    return result as Extract<AB, { type: K }>;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=39&ssc=2&pln=34&pc=1#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEFUG9ir6iATwAcoAuVAcgUoBpd8A3BAGwFdzUw2BbAI1jAAvsFCRYiFKgBC2BniKkKlPnXmpm7TgGcIMcAHNhoxWnSyAvBlQAfGQG5RcNmCQQQAezCpiMDym1tdAAKTQ4KdABKOXxUAHo41AA6FONgZ1d3Lx8-AO1pUNZwmWicWITk1JF0lzdPb19-KECABQQYBB4oaBhg4nbO7tgKXX0wA1pUKAAPUjcoABMAFRJOakpbKlVS9RA4VGCZuehl1dQLC6oaHdjYpC9dVBhmthYIc9QDbvQwBYBhAAWUCQAGs+gMuj1JkdgScVqRIo5bvhGnkQs9tK8IIj1CJYnsDjD5qdSOdLipKDdkah7mBHhisR8vhAfv8gaDwR1IbBobNYYt4VAcdSck1AgUGW9hfgRNUFsCWO00MwYKgFnwKAgwIRHBk6tlmazAcCQQAeADSU2m0F+2gw0gA2pRTJQALoAPk5gx6Iz0hl5xwFqwo5siFAAotaOm5TeZJlgCMHUJahO6YvhafSXm8PuqHf0uUMYK7UAg7eYkfgCcEAISS7HYAgAvwAdy4UDb4Zgfl6lAAch53nAPC4FpT7Kg8VX9sF60lTKga5ciXDVqUm63253ux5ewBVMArxaJ0jjyfqZ4QNgwbz10t2yN6ZAQWPSeMnzgp92OIRAA)

Here we use a type parameter `K` to capture the actual type that is passed in and we ensure that only a type in the union `AB` can be passed in (we use an [index access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content) to get the union of all possible types). We then use `Extract` to get the appropriate element from the union. (You can read a bit more abotut filtering unions [here](https://twitter.com/TitianCernicova/status/1504865444733276161?s=20&t=xVLhq82jki-ehFa9RFt29g))